# "field must exist" error in Simple Form application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a simple form where you can enter a user, their continent and language.

User belongs_to continent and language, and 
continent and language has_many users.

I ran the following three commands in bash:

```
$rails generate scaffold language name:string 

$rails generate scaffold continent name:string  

$rails g scaffold user name:string language:belongs_to continent:belongs_to
```

When I go to localhost:3000/languages and localhost:3000/continents and create new entries it says "Continent/Language" successfully created.

However, when I then proceed to attempt to create a new user, I get the error: "Language must exist" and "Continent must exist" even though they have been created.

What is the cause of the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is this:

1) Undo your User Scaffold `rails d scaffold User`

2) Then, be sure you delete any reference

3) Create the scaffold like this:

```
rails g scaffold User name:string
```

4) Create the corrsponding migration (this is really the best way in order to keep everything separate).

```
rails g migration AddContinetIdToUsers continent_id:intenger
```

5) Do the same for the languague:

```
rails g migration AddLanguageIdToUsers language_id:intenger
```

6) Go to your models and add the corresponding `has_many` and `belogns_to` associations.

7) It's all, you won't have any problem. Remember keep separete your migration for integrity and data manipulation

Sometimes you need to restart your server

Comment: The one line you suggested(
$ rails g scaffold User name:string) results in there not being fields to enter "language" and "continent" on the users page.

Comment: You are just adding the relathionship in the models.

You need to set the fields in your views. The fact you generate things in usings scaffolds, doesn't mean that will generate all logic.

You need to call in your views, the fields in order to set the languague and continent. 

Check this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

I think that's the reaons why @azeez3j asked about your views and controllers. You need to implement all the logic.

Regards